# E trernal Font Awesome overrides css code of my website

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-awesome

Hello i'm using `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css` and i have a strange issue.

This is my button:

```
<span class="fa fa-external-link-alt icona-link"></span>
```

CSS

```
.icona-link {
 float: right;
 font-size: 18px;
 width: 50px;
 min-height: 36px;
 background: #d9b560;
 display: -webkit-box !important;
 display: -ms-flexbox !important;
 display: flex !important;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
 -ms-flex-pack: center;
 justify-content: center;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 -ms-flex-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
 border: 2px solid #d9b560;
 color: #fff;
 padding-left: 7px;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**but the external source of fontawesome add this:**

```
.fa {
   font-size: inherit;
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
```

Why ? This is a big problem because it overrides my css code... how can i solve this ?

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english.

Thanks a lot

Comment: As for "why", it is because you are applying the class `.fa` to your element, so the properties set in the external Font Awesome stylesheet that apply to the `.fa` class are being called on that element.

Comment: Also, without the `font-family` set to `FontAwesome`, your result would not work because you need this font-family to display the font awesome icon properly, which is why you always have to use the `.fa` class with FontAwesome icons (or `.fas`, etc. for other styles).

Answer (score 0):

You could either add !important at the end of properties that are being overriden OR set them to initial if you simply don't want the properties from the external source.

So,

```
.div {
font-size:20px!important;
}

or

.div {
font-size:initial!important;
}
```